# The background does not appear after changing the position of div

Tags: css, background

I've the menu with this css :

```
div#menu {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;  
z-index: 1000;
height: 57px;
background:transparent url(../images/page_header_b.png) repeat-x;
}

#menu ul.menu {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

when i scroll i chnage the position of menu as this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

if($(window).scrollTop()>150) {
  $('div#menu').css( "z-index", "1000" );
  $('ul.menu').css( "top", "0" );
  $('ul.menu').css( "position", "fixed" );
}
});
```

The menu is fixed but without the background.

I try to do this when i scroll but it doesn't change

```
$('div#menu').css( "background", "transparent url(../images/page_header_b.png) repeat-x");
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `div#menu` contains the `ul` - You are moving the ul not the div that contains the background!  Move the `div` instead: `$('div#menu').css({ "position": fixed, "top": 0, "bottom": "auto" });`

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/elen/3xLkW/ ?

Comment: Thank'u @Pete and Elen, it work's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You should move your div to top like this-

```
          $(window).scroll(function () {

            $('div#menu').css("z-index", "1000");
            $('ul.menu').css("top", "0");
            $('ul.menu').css("position", "fixed");
            $('div#menu').css("top", "0");

    });
```